# Add file to a folder that is inside a zip file java

Tags: java, zip, nio

I am trying to add a txt file into a folder which is inside a zip file.
First, I was extracting all the contents of zip file then adding the txt file and then zipping back.
Then I read about the nio method which I can modify the zip without extracting it. Using this method I can add the txt file to the main folder of zip but I can't go deeper.

testing.zip file has res folder in it.

Here is my code:

```
        Path txtFilePath = Paths.get("\\test\\prefs.txt");
        Path zipFilePath = Paths.get("\\test\\testing.zip");
        FileSystem fs;
        try {
            fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipFilePath, null);
            Path fileInsideZipPath = fs.getPath("res/prefs.txt");  //when I remover "res/" code works.
            Files.copy(txtFilePath, fileInsideZipPath);
            fs.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: res/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(edit to give the actual answer)

Do:

```
fs.getPath("res").resolve("prefs.txt")
```

instead of:

```
fs.getPath("res/prefs.txt")
```

The `.resolve()` method will do the correct thing with regards to file separators etc.

Comment: Try and `fs.getPath("res").resolve("prefs.txt")`, then, instead of `fs.getPath("res/prefs.txt")`

Answer (score 2):

The `fs.getPath("res/prefs.txt")` should certainly work and you don't need to split it to `fs.getPath("res").resolve("prefs.txt")` as the approved answer says.

The exception `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: res/` is slightly confusing because it mentions file but in fact directory is missing.

I had a similar problem and all I had to do was:

```
if (fileInsideZipPath.getParent() != null)
   Files.createDirectories(fileInsideZipPath.getParent());
```

See full example:

```
@Test
public void testAddFileToArchive() throws Exception {
    Path fileToAdd1 = rootTestFolder.resolve("notes1.txt");
    addFileToArchive(archiveFile, "notes1.txt", fileToAdd1);

    Path fileToAdd2 = rootTestFolder.resolve("notes2.txt");
    addFileToArchive(archiveFile, "foo/bar/notes2.txt", fileToAdd2);

    . . . 
}


public void addFileToArchive(Path archiveFile, String pathInArchive, Path srcFile) throws Exception {        
    FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(archiveFile, null);
    Path fileInsideZipPath = fs.getPath(pathInArchive);
    if (fileInsideZipPath.getParent() != null) Files.createDirectories(fileInsideZipPath.getParent());
    Files.copy(srcFile, fileInsideZipPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    fs.close();
}
```

If I remove `Files.createDirectories()` bit, and ensure clear start with clear test directory, I get:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: foo/bar/
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.checkParents(ZipFileSystem.java:863)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.newOutputStream(ZipFileSystem.java:528)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.newOutputStream(ZipPath.java:792)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:285)
at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:3016)
at java.nio.file.CopyMoveHelper.copyToForeignTarget(CopyMoveHelper.java:126)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1277)
at my.home.test.zipfs.TestBasicOperations.addFileToArchive(TestBasicOperations.java:111)
at my.home.test.zipfs.TestBasicOperations.testAddFileToArchive(TestBasicOperations.java:51)
```